# Which type of image format for their app logo, famous app development companies use?

Tags: android, icons, png, blur, image-formats

I am starting to develop an android app but confused in making images better. When I use png logo and test the app, the logo appears blurred. What I can do to make quality images for logos?

Answer (score 0):

Add an application launcher icon with automatic size.

Follow these steps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HlYx.png

It will automatically re-size.

or visit official docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio